# Replace unicode characters

Tags: c#, encoding

I have string variable that contains some text. Text contains some special characters but they are unicode like &#263 which is Ć or &#262 which is ć and so on (Croatian letters). How to convert all those characters to show them as they should be?

For example my string looks like:

> AVI&#263

but it should be:

> AVIĆ

I had tried with this:

```
 Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-2");
 Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
 byte[] utfBytes = utf8.GetBytes(res6.ToString());
 byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, iso, utfBytes);
 string msg = iso.GetString(isoBytes);
```

But I don't get result that should be.

Comment: What is the string value of your res6.ToString()?

Comment: This one for example AVI&#263, just as I describe in first post.

Comment: `&#263` is almost, but not quite, an HTML entity (the trailing semicolon is missing). Nevertheless, `WebUtility.HtmlDecode` may still be of use.

Comment: I owe you a beer :) Thanks a lot!